# NetworkOnMainThreadException in xmpp connection Android Studio

Tags: android, xmpp

I am modifying an Android application. When I am running the app, all the functionalities work fine. But, in the backend, I am getting this error:

```
4008-4008/com.it.testApp W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

the line for the error is chatServise.java:

```
BaseActivity.xmppConnection.disconnect();
BaseActivity.xmppConnection = null;
```

I am using xmpp and smack for chat services.

The application is using this piece of code in other classes and no problems there. When I asked the development team, they told me that it is related to project setup. The application is working fine in every other aspects. I don't know how to solve this issue. Can anyone help?

My code is working perfectly in my previous developers system. But he won't help me. He only said **'you have to setup on server nodejs and need to do connection'** 
I don't understand how to connect to node.js from android studio,
I had spend 3 days on this and i couldn't find a solution. Can anyone help

I am adding full stack trace

05-25 11:51:46.433 3845-3845/com.it.example D/SMACK: 11:51:46 AM Connection closed (301630643)
05-25 11:51:46.433 3845-1453/com.it.example D/SMACK: 11:51:46 AM SENT (301630643): 
05-25 11:51:46.584 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1090)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1085)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.shutdown(XMPPConnection.java:456)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.disconnect(XMPPConnection.java:482)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.disconnect(Connection.java:490)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at com.it.example.util.ChatService.onStart(ChatService.java:49)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:458)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2904)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5311)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
05-25 11:51:46.594 3845-3845/com.it.example W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)

Comment: did you search your problem in SO ?

Comment: backend or background/log?

Comment: background log i am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is self explanatory you are running a network operation in the main thread.
You should allow all threads or find a more recent and efficient way to run the threads.
Use this code when you create the activity:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception). This question should be marked as duplicate actually.

Comment: bad workaround, but very helpful in testing something quickly. Thank you!